# What is the correct way of using Skyrim DLC's

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have completely devoured Skyrim last year, playing it a few months straight doing all the missions, getting all the masks, leveling up to max, etc.

In the meantime I changed computers a few times, so my saved games are all lost.

Now I recently got an xbox, with a free copy of Skyrim, and started to play it again. Now my question to you guys is the following:

Should I finish the game again, or main storyline, and then install the DLC's?

Should I install the DLC's one at a time, or can I install them all at once?

Should I maybe only install the latest DLC, because it maybe overwrites the others?

Or finally, can I just install all the DLC's and start a new game and just play like I am used to?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The DLC are completely independent and compatible with the original game, no matter your game progress or installation order.

Meaning, **you should install the game with all updates and DLC, and start playing as you like**.

Note that for Hearthfire you will need to complete some standard quests to be able to buy your land. And for Dawnguard you will have to be around level 10.

Comment: Ok cool, that's great to hear.